# Magento 2.0 REST API Oauth error

Tags: php, rest, magento, oauth

The below php script is our rest api to retrieve customer info as admin 
-The script is getting the admin login and authorize page correctly but after the authorize it is giving the error

> OAuthException Object ( [message:protected] => Invalid auth/bad
>   request (got a 403, expected HTTP/1.1 20X or a redirect)
>   [string:Exception:private] => [code:protected] => 403 [file:protected]
>   => /home/xxxx/public_html/oauth_admin.php [line:protected] => 39 [trace:Exception:private] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [file] =>
>   /home/xxxxx/public_html/oauth_admin.php [line] => 39 [function] =>
>   fetch [class] => OAuth [type] => -> [args] => Array ( [0] =>
>   http://www.xxxxx.com/api/rest/customers [1] => Array ( ) [2] => GET
>   [3] => Array ( [Content-Type] => application/xml [Accept] => / ) ) ) )
>   [previous:Exception:private] => [lastResponse] =>
>   {"messages":{"error":[{"code":403,"message":"Access denied"}]}}
>   [debugInfo] => Array ( [sbs] => xxxxx [body_recv] =>
>   {"messages":{"error":[{"code":403,"message":"Access denied"}]}} ) ))

I have tried every blog/post to try get this working and at this stage no doubt its something very obvious but I cant spot it...help greatly appreciated!

```
<?php
$callbackUrl = "http://www.site2.com/oauth_admin.php";
$temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl = "http://www.site1.com/oauth/initiate?oauth_callback=" . urlencode($callbackUrl);
$adminAuthorizationUrl = 'https://www.site1.com/admin/oauth_authorize';
$accessTokenRequestUrl = 'http://www.site1.com/oauth/token';
$apiUrl = 'http://www.site1.com/api/rest';
$consumerKey = 'xxxxx';
$consumerSecret = 'xxxxx';

session_start();
if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && isset($_SESSION['state']) && $_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
    $_SESSION['state'] = 0;
}
try {
    $authType = ($_SESSION['state'] == 2) ? OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION : OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI;
    $oauthClient = new OAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, $authType);
    $oauthClient->enableDebug();

    if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && !$_SESSION['state']) {
        $requestToken = $oauthClient->getRequestToken($temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl);
        $_SESSION['secret'] = $requestToken['oauth_token_secret'];
        $_SESSION['state'] = 1;
        header('Location: ' . $adminAuthorizationUrl . '?oauth_token=' . $requestToken['oauth_token']);
        exit;
    } else if ($_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
        $oauthClient->setToken($_GET['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
        $accessToken = $oauthClient->getAccessToken($accessTokenRequestUrl);
        $_SESSION['state'] = 2;
        $_SESSION['token'] = $accessToken['oauth_token'];
        $_SESSION['secret'] = $accessToken['oauth_token_secret'];
        header('Location: ' . $callbackUrl);
        exit;
    } else {
        $oauthClient->setToken($_SESSION['token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
        $resourceUrl = "$apiUrl/customers";
        //$oauthClient->fetch($resourceUrl);
        $oauthClient->fetch($resourceUrl, array(), 'GET', array('Content-Type' => 'application/xml', 'Accept' => '*/*'));
        $customers = json_decode($oauthClient->getLastResponse());
        print_r($customers);

    }
} catch (OAuthException $e) {
    print_r($e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment yet, but does the user have the correct roles? Had the same problem and it turned out to be a user that wasn't allowed to access parts of Magento.

Here's a link to the documentation of Magento which explains this: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/permission_settings/permission_settings.html

Also: go to System > Permissions and check if the user you use to connect to the api has the proper permissions.

Comment: Ive been doing more debugging and it seems everything is working fine for each of the oauth steps (verified in Postman rest client) and each of the admin rights are set correctly.  The 403 error is showing on the logs as **client denied by server configuration: /home/xxxxx/public_html/app/etc/local.xml**

Comment: That's not the problem. It happens sometimes. Just out of curiosity: why aren't you using something like this [http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/customer/customer.info.html]